# Where can I find the minhagim of Algeria?

Tags: minhag, product-recommendation, jewish-books, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

Is there a compilation of all the minagim of Algeria, especially for the Setifian custom?

Answer (score 5):

I found this two books, one on HebrewBooks: [חסד ואמת - מנהגי ק"ק אלג'יר](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/8834) and one on GoogleBooks: [זה השולחן](http://books.google.co.il/books/about/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%96%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F.html?id=VvnVcQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y), they should deal with Algeria Minhagim...

And there is a list of many other Jewish Books from Algeria in [This Page](http://www.yahadut-algeria.co.il/sifreykodesh.html), you may find useful too.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I found a sidour and other sefarim but no sefer related to minhagim. Also, regarding the book on HebrewBook, do you have the others chapters?

Comment: Nope :\ sorry, but no other chapters there... I ask at my yeshiva if they know any other books though...